# Function for the intersections of lines tangent to $a^x$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)=a^x$. Show that for every pair of points on $f$ with constant distance $n$ between their x-coordinates, the lines tangent to $f$ at those points intersect each other on the function

$$e\ln\left(a\right)\left(\frac{n}{a^n-1}\right)a^{\left(x-\frac{n}{a^n-1}\right)}$$

I proved this, but want to see how someone else would go about proving it.

Comment: What's the "informal" way about doing this?

Comment: Sorry - Wrong wording.

Comment: We could provide a new way, if we knew the way that you've done it.

Comment: I don’t mean it has to be a different proof. But one would expect some amount of uniqueness in someone else’s thought process and I’m interested to see any.